# Image Upload without refreshing and change of background

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Okay, so I've been on the search for an answer for weeks now.

### **Disclaimer**

I'm new to Web development and I've learnt all by my own. Sometimes I get stuck but I've never been this stuck before.

## The Problem

I want to have an Upload button on my site that automatically uploads the image to a folder and changes the background image of the same page without being redirected. This image's Path will be stored in a cookie that the user will load each time he accesses the page and the same image will be loaded as the background image. Exactly the same that Google does on its standard Tabbing page on the right bottom of the screen.

I've researched and apparently AJAX is perfect for this scenario since it enables for JQuery to mediate the php file. However I cant seem to understand how to use it in the way I need it.

This is what I have for the button, php file and the JQuery AJAX function:

The code I just showed you doesn't seem to work.

#### index.php

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" id="file_uploader">
    <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
    <button  class="btn">Upload</button>
    <input  id="image_upload" type="file" name="file"/>  
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" style="visibility:none;"></button> 
    </div>                                                                                       
    </form>
```

#### .js

```
    $(document).ready(function (e){
    $("#uploadForm").on('submit',(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    url: "upload.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { imageurl : $final,},
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(result) {
    alert($final);
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = $final;
    },
    error: function(){}             
    });
    }));
    });
```

#### .php

```
    if(isset($_FILES['userImage'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['userImage']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['userImage']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['userImage']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$file_name)));
      
      $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");
      
      if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }
      
      $final = "url(Uploads/".$file_name.")";
      
      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"Uploads/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
```

Because I am using XAMPP to test before committing, it doesn't work yet, but not even the image is changing.

Comment: I cannot find `uploadForm` in your index.php Can you log to check if your on submit is being called?

Comment: first glance error:  visibility:none; should be visibility:hidden; (if you want the button to be invisible). Also, you haven't declared the 'final' variable in your js

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some of your ID's you're referencing in your JS file doesn't seem to match your HTML code.

```
// Original
$('#uploadForm').on('submit', function(e) { ... }
// Should it be?
$('#file_uploader').on('submit', function(e) { ... }
```

Also

```
// Where is $final defined and is the extra coma required?
data: { imageURL : $final,},
```

This is what I use to upload CSV files. It might work in your situation also.

JS

```
var formData = new FormData();
var fileName = $('#image_upload').val();
var file = $('#image_upload').prop('files')[0];
formData.append('file', file);

$.ajax({
    url: uploadURL, // PHP file to handle uploads
    dataType: 'text',  // Expected return type
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,                         
    type: 'post',
    success: function(response){
        // Handle response
        var path = 'path to image upload dir';
        $('#bgImage').css('background-image', path + response);
    }
});
```

PHP

```
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
}
else {
    $path =  'path to image upload dir';
    $image = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path . $_FILES['file']['name']);

    setcookie("bg_image", $image, time()+3600, "/", "example.com");
    echo $image;

}
```

Not saying this is going to perfectly fix your problem, but hopefully it'll help you get to a working solution.